# PHPUnit mock return value and number of times called with specific argument for different methods same class

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

My scenario is similar to below:

```
class ToMock
{
    public function iReturn()
    {
        return time();
    }

    public function callMe1($arg1, $arg2)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function callMe2($arg1, $arg2)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

class ToTest
{
    public function feedMe(ToMock $toMock)
    {
        if ($toMock->iReturn() > 100) {
            $toMock->callMe1(5, 10);
        }

        if ($toMock->iReturn() < 200) {
            $toMock->callMe2(15, 20);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I want to test if `ToMock::iReturn()` returns 150, `ToTest::feedMe()` calls `ToMock::callMe1()` once with 5 and 10, and `ToMock::callMe2()` once with 15 and 20.

I know I can mock the `ToMock::iReturn` to return 150, also I can mock `ToMock` to expect a particular method once with supplied argument. But, is it possible to do all of these together in the same time? if yes, how would it look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is.

Here's an example of a test that covers `ToTest`:

```
<?php

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class ToTestTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @dataProvider providerTimeBetween0And100
     *
     * @param int $time
     */
    public function testFeedMeWhenTimeIsBetween0And100($time)
    {
        $toMock = $this->createMock(ToMock::class);

        $toMock
            ->expects($this->exactly(2))
            ->method('iReturn')
            ->willReturn($time);

        $toMock
            ->expects($this->never())
            ->method('callMe1');

        $toMock
            ->expects($this->once())
            ->method('callMe2')
            ->with(
                $this->identicalTo(15),
                $this->identicalTo(20)
            );

        $toTest = new ToTest();

        $toTest->feedMe($toMock);
    }

    public function providerTimeBetween0And100()
    {
        return $this->providerTimeBetween(0, 100);
    }

    /**
     * @dataProvider providerTimeBetween101And199
     *
     * @param int $time
     */
    public function testFeedMeWhenTimeIsBetween101And199($time)
    {
        $toMock = $this->createMock(ToMock::class);

        $toMock
            ->expects($this->exactly(2))
            ->method('iReturn')
            ->willReturn($time);

        $toMock
            ->expects($this->once())
            ->method('callMe1')
            ->with(
                $this->identicalTo(5),
                $this->identicalTo(10)
            );

        $toMock
            ->expects($this->once())
            ->method('callMe2')
            ->with(
                $this->identicalTo(15),
                $this->identicalTo(20)
            );

        $toTest = new ToTest();

        $toTest->feedMe($toMock);
    }

    public function providerTimeBetween101And199()
    {
        return $this->providerTimeBetween(101, 199);
    }
    /**
     * @dataProvider providerTimeGreaterThan199
     *
     * @param int $time
     */
    public function testFeedMeWhenTimeIsGreaterThan199($time)
    {
        $toMock = $this->createMock(ToMock::class);

        $toMock
            ->expects($this->exactly(2))
            ->method('iReturn')
            ->willReturn($time);

        $toMock
            ->expects($this->once())
            ->method('callMe1')
            ->with(
                $this->identicalTo(5),
                $this->identicalTo(10)
            );

        $toMock
            ->expects($this->never())
            ->method('callMe2');

        $toTest = new ToTest();

        $toTest->feedMe($toMock);
    }

    public function providerTimeGreaterThan199()
    {
        return $this->providerTimeBetween(200, 300);
    }

    private function providerTimeBetween($min, $max)
    {
        for ($time = $min; $time < $max; ++$time) {
            yield [
                $time
            ];
        }
    }
}
```

Note how multiple expectations are set up using `expects()` and further constraints. All of these can be easily combined.

For reference, see:

- https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects
- https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects.tables.matchers

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly then test code could look like

```
class MockingExpectationsTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    private $obj;
    private $mock;

    public function setUp(){
        $this->mock = $this->createMock(ToMock::class);
        $this->obj = new ToTest();
    }

    public function testExpectations(){
        $this->mock->expects($this->exactly(2))
                   ->method('iReturn')
                   ->willReturn(150);
        $this->mock->expects($this->exactly(1))
                   ->method('callMe1')
                    ->with(5, 10);
        $this->mock->expects($this->exactly(1))
                   ->method('callMe2')
                    ->with(15, 20);
        $this->obj->feedMe($this->mock);
    }
}
```